# How to plot in PYthon a BarChart that depicts the number of observations that for each label of a categorical variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I know this is very simple but I don't truly know how to do it as I don't usually plot and it's giving me headache. I have two particular problems:

1º Let's imagine I just have an column of a dataframe (or let's say, and array) with a categorical(object) variable and I would like to make a Bar Chart with the number of observations that have the different labels of that chart. For example if I have that dataframe with this column named color I would like something like this.(click on the image below)

```
    COLOR
0   green
1   red
2   green
3   yellow
4   pink
5   red
6   blue
```

[Here you have an image of what I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT04t.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in a dataframe, or a dataframe column, you could use the built-in [`df.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) or [`df.hist()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) functions:

```py
import pandas as pd
# The data
data = {'COLOR': ['green', 'red', 'green', 'yellow', 'pink', 'red', 'blue']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# The plot
df['COLOR'].value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
# or, more straight forward : 
df['COLOR'].hist()
```

which yields the expected output:
[image]

Comment: Or maybe `df_counts = df['COLOR'].value_counts(); df_counts.plot(kind='bar', color=df_counts.index, rot=0)`?

Comment: yes, most definitely, but I wasn't sure the column would always be a 'color'!